# MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController and AVFullScreenViewController first time comes in portrait mode

Tags: ios, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, xcode6.1

There are too many questions related to landscape issue in MPMovieplayer. My application is in portrait mode.But i wanna video in landscape mode.I already have landscape/portrait functionality for video. I am using the following code:

```
static NSString * const VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS7 = @"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController";
static NSString * const VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS8 = @"AVFullScreenViewController";

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
  if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS7)] ||
    [[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS8)]) 
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

}

The Code is working fine in both iOS 7 and iOS8.
But the problem is that video first open in portrait mode while device is in landscape mode.After a change in orientation than app works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any way to call manually the following method:

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window

          or any other way to update orientation for mpmovieplayer manually.So it will solve my problem.

Comment: can you try below code,
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

[[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
[[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
[[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];

Put above code when video is played. Above code is for iPhone 4 screen size, Change the value according to your device screen size.

Comment: @sundeep i am add the above code to the method when video start notification is fired.But bad luck its not working at my end.Video screen is not rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long R&D and different-different approaches and spending 2-3 days.Finally i got an answer with the help of my friend.If our view controller is in portrait mode than the following code is not able to push  player view in landscape view.

```
static NSString * const VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS7 = @"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController";
static NSString * const VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS8 = @"AVFullScreenViewController";

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
  if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS7)] ||
[[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(VIDEO_CONTROLLER_CLASS_NAME_IOS8)]) 
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
else {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

In my case problem is that my UIWebView container view Controller very time comes in portrait mode.I do not know after push ViewController in the UINavigationController following orientation methods not called for that ViewController.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate;  
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

To solve this issue i will add the following code in the ViewDidLoad method

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

And in following code in viewWillDisappear

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

The above code finally solve my issue.

Thanks to all who was support me to solve this issue.

Comment: @tomDev You can fix the warning by replacing the method name with:- `(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:( UIWindow *)window`

Comment: Anyone found a way to implement this on Swift?

Comment: how about iOS9 and iOS10?